# Run Spring Boot Unit tests ignoring CommandLineRunner

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm trying to write spring boot unit tests but have some problems with CommandLineRunner which runs entire app when I run unit tests.

**App.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Profile("!test")
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  private ReportService reportService;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
    app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    app.run(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length == 0)
      reportService.generateReports();

    if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("-p"))
      for (Report report : reportService.showReports())
        System.out.println(report.getId() + " : " + report.getTimestamp());
  }
}
```

**ReportServiceTest.class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ReportServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private ReportRepository reportRepository;

  @Autowired
  private ReportService reportService;

  @Test
  public void testShowReports() {
    List<Report> expectedReports = new ArrayList<>(3);
    for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
      expectedReports.add(reportRepository.save(new Report()));
    }

    List<Report> actualReports = reportService.showReports();
    assertEquals(expectedReports.size(), actualReports.size());
  }
```

What I need to do that CommandLineRunner will be ignored when run in tests but all ApplicationContext, JPA and so on will be initialized?

**UPDATE**

It seems I have found the solution:

- Added @Profile("!test") to App.class
- Created new AppTest.class in test directory where I initialize only SpringApplication without CommandLineRunner
- Added @ActiveProfile("test") to ReportServiceTest.class

---

**AppTest.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Profile("test")
public class AppTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(AppTest.class);
    app.setLogStartupInfo(false);
    app.run(args);
  }
}
```