# connection pooling for Firestore spring application

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, concurrency, spring-data, database-connection, connection-pooling

Similar to Spring Data, can connection pooling be done on [Firestore](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/Firestore.html)/[CollectionReference](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/CollectionReference.html). The [quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) shows steps to create connections for reading/writing, but could not locate if these Java objects support concurrency.

Not: referring [Database Connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041114/what-is-database-pooling) , not [http pooling](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-tips-connection-pooling).

Comment: Hi @Raj, Are you pertaining to [HTTP connection pooling](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-tips-connection-pooling)? You can use HTTP connection pooling just include Firebase in your import statements.

Comment: @marc-anthony-b , I am looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool , I edited question also slightly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection pooling allows you to re-use objects that are expensive to create. The Firestore SDK already re-uses such objects behind the scenes, and there's neither a need nor a way to influence this.

The Firestore object itself is already cached by the SDK, or at least its expensive internals are. A `CollectionReference` object is lightweight wrapper for a path in the database, so it's cheap to create.

Comment: thanks , https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/#autoconfiguration-3 mentions Spring Boot autoconfiguration creates the following bean ... an instance of Firestore from the Google Cloud Java Client for Firestore , so I suppose that bean is thread safe for concurrency and no connection pooling may be necessary, guessing ..

Comment: The Firestore SDK already re-uses objects that are expensive to create behind the scenes. But if you aren't certain, it should be fairly easy to measure that in your code.