# how can I keep a database connection in the bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, disnake

I am writing a discord bot and it needs access to 2 databases, but after a while the connection closes and the commands stop working. I wrote a code that executes this line every 100 seconds, but I think it's wrong.

```py
@Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self) -> None:
    if not self.ping_databases.is_running():
        self.ping_databases.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def ping_databases(self):
    if Config.DATABASE_AUTORECONNECT:
        database_mta.connection.ping(reconnect=True)
        database_bot.connection.ping(reconnect=True)
```

I also tried to execute it in `on_slash_command`, but the commands are executed faster than the second database has time to connect.

Comment: Use a [database pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041114/what-is-database-pooling)