# How to find out the optimal amount of threads?

Tags: multithreading

I'm planning to make a software with lot of peer to peer like network connections. Normally I would create an own thread for every connection to send and receive data, but in this case with 300-500+ connections it would mean continuously creating and destroying a lot of threads which would be a big overhead I guess. And making one thread that handles all the connections sequentially could probably slow down things a little. (I'm not really sure about this.)

The question is: how many threads would be optimal to handle this kind of problems? Would it be possible to calculate it in the software so it can decide itself to create less threads on an old computer with not as much resources and more on new ones?

It's a theoretical question, I wouldn't like to make it implementation or language dependant. However I think a lot of people would advice something like "Just use a `ThreadPool`, it will handle stuff like that" so let's say it will not be a .NET application. (I'll probably has to use some other parts of the code in an old Delphi project, so the language will be probably Delphi or maybe C++ but it's not decided yet.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481970/how-many-threads-is-too-many/481979#481979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is Windows (you did mention .Net?), you should definitely implement this using [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28VS.85%29.aspx).  This is **the** most efficient way to do Windows sockets I/O.  There is an I/O-specific discussion of thread pool size at that documentation link.

> The most important property of an I/O
>   completion port to consider carefully
>   is the concurrency value. The
>   concurrency value of a completion port
>   is specified when it is created with
>   CreateIoCompletionPort via the
>   NumberOfConcurrentThreads parameter.
>   This value limits the number of
>   runnable threads associated with the
>   completion port. When the total number
>   of runnable threads associated with
>   the completion port reaches the
>   concurrency value, the system blocks
>   the execution of any subsequent
>   threads associated with that
>   completion port until the number of
>   runnable threads drops below the
>   concurrency value.

Basically, your reads and writes are all asynchronous and are serviced by a thread pool whose size you can modify.  But try it with the default first.

A good, free example of how to do this is at [the Free Framework](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html).  There are some gotchas that looking at working code could help you short-circuit.

Answer (score 10):

Understanding the performance of your application under load is key, as mentioned before profiling, measurements and re-testing is the way to go.

As a general guide [Goetz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0730.html) talks about having

> threads = number of CPUs + 1

for CPU bound applications, and

> number of CPUs * (1 + wait time / service time)

for IO bound contexts

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the number of threads configurable.
2. Target a few specific configurations that are the most common ones that you expect to support.
3. Get a good performance profiler / instrument your code and then rigorously test with different values of 1. for all the different types of 2. till you find an optimal value that works for each configuration.

I know, this might seem like a not-so smart way to do things but i think when it comes to performance, benchmarking the results via testing is the only sure-fire way to really know how well / badly it will work.

Edit: +1 to the question whose link is posted by paxDiablo above as a comment. Its almost the same question and theres loads of information there including a very detailed reply by paxDiablo himself.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a calculation based on cpu speed, cores, and memory space in your install and set a constant somewhere to tell your application how many threads to use.  Semaphores and thread pools come to mind.

Personally I would separate the listening sockets from the sending ones and open sending sockets in runtime instead of running them as daemons; listening sockets can run as daemons.

Multithreading can be its own headache and introduce many bugs.  The best thing to do is make a thread do one thing and block when processing to avoid undesired and unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

One thread per CPU, processing several (hundreds) connections.