# Design Pattern - Spring KafkaListener processing 1 million records in 1 hour

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-kafka

My spring boot application is going to listen to 1 million records an hour from a kafka broker. The entire processing logic for each message takes 1-1.5 seconds including a database insert. Broker has 64 partitions, which is also the concurrency of my @KafkaListener.

My current code is only able to process 90 records in a minute in a lower environment where I am listening to around 50k records an hour. Below is the code and all other config parameters like max.poll.records etc are default values:

```
@KafkaListener(id="xyz-listener", concurrency="64", topics="my-topic")
public void listener(String record) {

// processing logic 

}
```

I do get "it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group" 7-8 times an hour. I think both of these issues can be solved through isolating listener method and multithreading processing of each message but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few points to consider here. First, 64 consumers seems a bit too much for a single application to handle consistently.

Considering each poll by default fetches `500 records` per consumer at a time, your app might be getting overloaded and causing the consumers to get kicked out of the group if a single batch takes more than the 5 minutes default for `max.poll.timeout.ms` to be processed.

So first, I'd consider `scaling the application horizontally` so that each application handles a smaller amount of partitions / threads.

A second way to increase throughput would be using a [batch listener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#batch-listeners), and handling processing and DB insertions in batches as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369462/optimizing-data-fetching-and-insertion-in-spring-boot/72370912#72370912).

Using both, you should be processing a sensible amount of work in parallel per app, and should be able to achieve your desired throughput.

Of course, you should load test each approach with different figures to have proper metrics.

EDIT: Addressing your comment, if you want to achieve this throughput I wouldn't give up on batch processing just yet. If you do the DB operations row by row you'll need a lot more resources for the same performance.

If your rule engine doesn't do any I/O you can iterate each record from the batch through it without losing performance.

About data consistency, you can try some strategies. For example, you can have a `lock` to ensure that even through a rebalance only one instance will process a given batch of records at a given time - or perhaps there's a more idiomatic way of handling that in Kafka using the rebalance hooks.

With that in place, you can batch load all the information you need to filter out duplicated / outdated records when you receive the records, iterate each record through the rule engine in memory, and then batch persist all results, to then release the lock.

Of course, it's hard to come up with an ideal strategy without knowing more details about the process. The point is by doing that you should be able to handle around 10x more records within each instance, so I'd definitely give it a shot.

Comment: Another note: if you do `concurrency="64"`, you need to ensure your have 64 cores of CPU on the machine you are going to run this. Technically the concurrency in Java is just delegation to native OS threads, which does not exceed the number of available CPUs. So, yes, if you'd like such a good performance, consider to scale your app horizontally . So, different partitions are going to be handled on different machines.

Comment: Sure, if processing is mainly `CPU-bound` it makes no sense having more threads than cores. If processing involves `I/O` however, having more threads than cores up to a limit is usually beneficial because at some point the thread will be stuck waiting for data and another thread can benefit from the core during that time. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015714/how-to-get-an-ideal-number-of-threads-in-parallel-programs-in-java) explains this a little further, but I failed to find a proper resource that wasn't too lengthy on the topic.

Comment: Yep! That was good to know. Anyway I remember back in days that my program on machine with 8 CPUs stops showing a good performance after 10 concurrent threads. So, yeah, probably that IO-bound assumption makes sense...

Comment: Yeah, for example, that's how before `NIO` a server such `Tomcat` was able to handle `100 concurrent requests` on the `one thread per request model` on machines with much less cores. `Loom` is set to change a lot on this; there's actually an interesting [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/gunnarmorling/status/1530151239643963392) where Loom's project lead explains it a bit

Comment: @Tomaz Even if I use batch listener, I still have to process each message separately through a rule engine and separate insertions are needed to keep track of duplicate/outdated records that I receive from Kafka. My process does not involve I/O, so maybe I can try reducing concurrency and try horizontal scaling.

Comment: @definepi314, I've edited the answer to address your comment. By reducing concurrency and scaling horizontally you should have a good throughput gain, but might still need lots of instances to achieve the throughput you want.

Comment: Hi @definepi314, were you able to improve performance? If you could share your results it’d be great. Thanks!

Comment: Horizontal scaling will be my second step, first I'll have to optimize processing time for each record whose logic we didn't discuss here. Sure, I'll let you know about the performance.