# How Many Threads Workings properly if I create many

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I did a project and it has 21 threads running at the same time.

But at this time I need to increase threads counter like 84 threads.

Is this possible or in the future may my application crash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481970/how-many-threads-is-too-many

Comment: Once I tested such a thing. My code launched 1k threads. At this amount sometimes I reached oversubscription, sometimes not. So 84 threads are ok.