# Python loop causing "error: [Errno 105] No buffer space available"

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a loop that goes through a Range(300) and creates a Thread with 'import threading'.. So this creates 300 threads, which is correct.

However I'm getting a problem where not all the threads start up, and a error is shown in console. as below

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/supersocket.py", line 29, in send
return self.outs.send(sx)
error: [Errno 105] No buffer space available
```

**Q:** Is there a way I can increase the buffer?

**Q:** Is this a python limit, or a process limit?

Comment: Do you really need 300 threads or just want to execute 300 (function, arguments) pairs using multiple threads? If so, try `concurrent.futures`.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481970/how-many-threads-is-too-many

Comment: I use scapy to do a sendp (send packet function)300 threads, and I would like all ~300 iterations to be started at the same time. I have never used `concurrent.futures`

Comment: `concurrent.futures` is working for me. Thanks @BartoszMarcinkowski

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`concurrent.futures` is working for me. Thank @BartoszMarcinkowski.

what I did was as follows.

```
import concurrent.futures

for i in my_list:
   concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1).submit(start_my_function)
```

Comment: If you create a `ThreadPoolExecuter` _per task_ it is just a much more complex way of simply starting a thread per task by `threading.Thread(target=start_my_function).start()`. If your ”solution” avoids hitting any limits it is just because the additional overhead prevents too many threads started/running at the same time, but purely as an accident. A different operating system or faster computer might show the same resource exhaustion as the original code.

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest using _one_ `ThreadPoolExecuter` for _all_ tasks, i.e. using that API as it was intended.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to limit the amount of concurrent threads is to use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. Create an instance with the maximum number of threads as argument:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(100)
for i in range(300):
   executor.submit(do_something, i)
```