# Python threading: "Can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown" when negligible amount of threads

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm working on a personal project called ResponsiBlock that interfaces with the HOSTS file as one of its main functions. It has an input>evaluate loop, and uses two threads maximum via the `threading` library: one thread called `MainThread` ensures all necessary files are set up and starts the execution loop, which from then on largely runs on `MainThread`; then, if the user decides that they want to unblock a site for a certain amount of time by eg. invoking `UNBLOCK-FOR category-of-related-sites>site-nickname number-minutes` as in `UNBLOCK-FOR social>reddit 5` the program says "OK", runs an `UNBLOCK category>nick` command with authorization (which, unlike `UNBLOCK-FOR`, is permanently in force until undone with an inverse `BLOCK category>nick` command; the user, with certain sites, is not allowed to run an unfettered `UNBLOCK` command because, using Reddit as an example, if they were allowed to unblock it without timing themselves, they could be stuck there for 6 hours unable to motivate themselves to get off). Anyway, it says ok, runs an `UNBLOCK` command, and in another thread `TimerThread` starts a timer for however many minutes the timer was set for, then after that time runs an inverting `BLOCK` command on the user's behalf.

That should be a maximum of two threads.

Buuuut at certain points when I try to run an `UNBLOCK-FOR` command it tosses `RuntimeError: Can't start new thread at interpreter shutdown` error, crashing the program, which seems to imply that it was dealing with a ridiculous number of threads and gave up.

I ran `threading.active_count()` and it said `2` (this is before even starting a new thread, so it's one more than AFAIK should be running), but running [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406494) with `x=500` (`x=1 million` froze the terminal and about froze everything else and I panic `Ctrl+C`'ed because nothing was happening after 30 seconds and I didn't want to fry something.) says that I should be able to handle that number easy. I'd provide code, but I don't know what y'all need. Please let me know.

Comment: First I am curious why you think that the error message implies a ridiculous number of threads.  "Interpreter shutdown" means that Python is attempting to exit the script, either because of an exception or because of a system.exit call.  So it seems that shutdown code somehow triggers an attempt to launch a new thread.  This would have nothing to do with the current number of threads.  It would not cause the program to crash - it looks to me that the program has _already_ crashed and is in the process of exiting.