# Execute a command in a rate by n requests per second

Tags: python

I want to execute an method-call in a variable rate of amount of calls per second. `n` equals the amount of calls i want to execute in one second. (rather to sleep for seconds, i need to sleep in milliseconds.)
I did it this way:

```
While True:
    method()
    time.sleep(1/n)
```

Now i would like to know if you know a more elegant and efficient way or is this already good?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's not elegant, it's wrong: imagine that your method takes 0.1 seconds and you want to have it run 10 times a second, then it will just run 5 times, which is wrong. In other programming languages, there are `Timer` classes, which give the opportunity to launch a method every time a certain time limit is reached. I'll advise you to follow such an approach.

Answer (score 0):

This will e the most efficient way to do it I think as you can assign multiple tasks and create new threads without straining your memory

```
import threading
n=3
def do_task():
  threading.Timer(1/n, do_task).start()
  print ("done")

do_task()
```

Comment: But in this case  i can't be sure that the processor works off every Thread in the rate i want the command line to be executed. For small rates like `n = 30`calls per second, there could be a queue which the processor can't come after. whereas i use just the `time.sleep`-method there is only one thread i can be sure the processor can run in the rate i want

Comment: Refer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481970/how-many-threads-is-too-many

Answer (score 0):

If your method just a separate background task, not have much interact with your other parts of logic, E.g. the task just try to get something from web. Then you may use [celery](https://github.com/celery/celery/), but if a function inside your program which not so easy to be separated, then bypass my answer.

An example to do a sum function 10 times in one second.

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks',
             broker='redis://localhost',
             backend='redis://localhost')

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls add(1, 2) every 1/n seconds, here, n=10
    sender.add_periodic_task(0.1, add.s(1, 2), name='add every 1/n seconds')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    print("running...", x, y)
    return x + y
```

**How to use?**

Install redis and celery first.

The in the folder of `tasks.py`.

In terminal 1 execute: `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info`

In termial 2 execute: `celery -A tasks beat --loglevel=info`

Then the function `add` will be run every 0.1 seconds.