# Maximum number of pending tkinter after events

Tags: python, tkinter, events, tk-toolkit

Is there a defined limit on the number of `tkinter` `after` events that can be pending?

This number can get big if for example a worker thread posts `after` events faster than tkinter can process them.

What happens if this limit is exceeded?

Comment: How do You think what would happen (if there was a limit in the first place (which I don't know but a certain set limit would be Your computer's memory))? it will crash (by logic at least)

Comment: @Matiiss: `tkinter` could for example discard new events or overwrite old pending ones.

Comment: _"What happens if this limit is exceeded?"_ - that should be trivial to figure out. Create a function that takes a second to complete, then call `after` repeatedly until tkinter crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is probably hardware related. There are different advice on *how to use threads*. Some say you shouldn't use threads at all and others are fine with it. Anyway, if your hardware can't afford your requested tasks your application will crash.

`Tkinter` schedules its after methods not exactly by time, it schedules it **after** a period of time and the task is on top of the list to do. So in fact, tkinter sets no limits to the tasks your hardware do.

[For reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/481979/13629335)

Comment: Btw `tkinter`'s `.after` scripts are run in the thread where the `.mainloop()` was called. I don't know why you linked that stackoverflow answer.

Comment: @TheLizzard well, just because its mentioned in the Question. Read carfully

Comment: So we are agreeing that tkinter doesn't use threads when running `.after` scripts. So my question is why did you link a stackoverflow answer that talks about the maximum number of threads? It seem unrelated

Comment: *This number can get big if for example a worker thread posts after events*

Comment: Generally it is discouraged to use tkinter methods (including `.after(...)`) when using using threads. So if you follow that rule, you should only call tkinter methods from 1 thread (the main thread most of the time).